# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2\n3'

Tags: python, list

I would like to convert my text file below into a list:

```
4,9,2
3,5,7
8,1,6
```

Here's my python code so far, but I couldn't understand why it doesn't work:

```
def main():
file = str(input("Please enter the full name of the desired file (with extension) at the prompt below: \n"))
print (parseCSV(file))

def parseCSV(file):

  file_open = open(file)
  #print (file_open.read())

  with open(file) as f:
    d = f.read().split(',')
    data = list(map(int, d))
    print (data)

main()
```

The error message is:

```
line 12, in parseCSV
data = list(map(int, d))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2\n3'
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `d = f.read().split(',')`, you're reading the entire file and splitting on commas. Since the file consists of multiple lines, it will contain newline characters. These characters are not removed by `split(',')`.

To fix this, iterate over the lines first instead of splitting the whole thing on commas:

```
d = (item for line in f for item in line.split(','))
```

Answer (score 0):

Read is reading the entire file (including the newlines).  So your actual data looks like:

```
'4,9,2\n3,5,7\n8,1,6'
```

You can either read the content in a single line at a time using

```
d = f.readline().split(',')
while d != "":
    data = list(map(int, d))
    print(data)
    d = f.readline().split(',')
```

Or, you can handle the new lines ("\n" and or "\n\r") as follows:

```
d = f.readline().replace("\n", ",").split(',')
```

Answer (score 0):

`f.read()` will read everything including the `newline character` (`\n`) and so `map(int, d)` will spit out error.

```
with open(file) as f:
    for line in f:
        d = line.split(',')
        data = list(map(int, d))
        print (data)
```

`for line in f` is a standard way to read a file line by line in python

Answer (score 0):

You need to split by newlines (`'\n'`), in this case you should use `csv` library.

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('foo.csv') as f:
        print [map(int, row) for row in csv.reader(f)]


[[4, 9, 2], [3, 5, 7], [8, 1, 6]]
```